# mysql indexes : multiple Key_name with the same name

Tags: mysql, indexing

i wanted to see the indexes of a table

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM images
```

this is what i got

```
   **Key_name**          **Column_name**
    user_id           user_id
    user_id           tags
    user_id           confirm
    insert_date_time  insert_date_time
    insert_date_time  category
    insert_date_time  confirm
```

i'm confused , why there's so much user_id and insert_date_time   under key_name ? 
i'm pretty sure they are not duplicate  .

why there is 2 index for `confirm` under different key names?

i've added the indexes in phpmyadmin by simply clicking on index .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the key whatever you want. In this case you have three keys named `user_id` and three named `insert_date_time`, where two of them in fact are on other columns. Also it seems you have duplicate keys for confirm.